# Setting up a special secondary display on iMac

Tags: mac, imac, imovie

I am a video editor and I have seen 2-display video setups a where one monitor is used for the editing software, and the secondary monitor is used to preview the edited footage. How would I be able to set this up on an iMac, if at all possible?

Comment: What software do you use for editing?

Answer (score 1):

The operating system supports multi screens. For the iMac i would say that a [DisplayLink](http://www.displaylink.com/support/mac_downloads.php) adapter would allow you to connect additional screens via USB. I've never used it, so I have no idea what the maximum resolution is, but I read several times on different boards that this solution has been successfully used.

Update: As [gabesubdo](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/26176/gabesubdo) mentioned in a comment below, it is not necessary to use a DisplayLink if your iMac has one or more Thunderbolt ports, which can be used as Mini Displayports as well. Apple provides adapters for Mini Displayports (to HDMI, VGA, ...)

Comment: DisplayLink is unnecessary here, the iMac has 1 or 2 Thunderbolt ports that can be used as Mini-DisplayPort for external displays. I don't understand the question, it's just a matter of obtaining a display and plugging it in. Mini-DisplayPort adapters are cheap and readily available.